# PhantomJS black render and error (Error downloading)

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, render

when I use PhantomJS with some proxy, Phantomjs gives me an black render with an error.

Command : /var/www/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs --proxy=62.37.237.31:8080 --debug=true /var/www/screen.js https://stackoverflow.com/ /var/www/screens/img.jpg

Error : 2017-03-20T14:26:44 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::Net workError(ContentNotFoundError) ( "Error downloading https://stackoverflow.com/ - server replied: Not Found" ) URL: "https://stackoverflow.com/"

Render : [Render black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9SaI.jpg)

I do not know what to do. Thank you

Comment: not sure if phantomjs is supposed to open a webpage

Comment: @singsuyash PhantomJS is a browser, how is it not supposed to open a web page?

Comment: 1) screen.js contents is kind of important, can you put it into your question? 2) is your proxy absolutely 100% positively working?

Comment: @Vaviloff, agreed. just trying to understand.

Comment: My screen.js : "use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
address, output, ref, user_agent;

address = system.args[1];
output = system.args[2];
ref = system.args[3];
user_agent = system.args[4];

page.settings.userAgent = user_agent;
page.zoomFactor = 0.25;

var settings = {
headers: {
  "Referer": ref
 }
}; 

page.open(address, settings, function () {
 
 page.render(output, {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
 phantom.exit();

});

Comment: Black capture : /var/www/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs --proxy=125.141.200.5:80 --debug=true /var/www/screen.js http://www.google.com /var/www/screens/image.jpg

No black capture : /var/www/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs --proxy=123.30.238.16:3128 --debug=true /var/www/screen.js http://www.google.com /var/www/screens/image.jpg


The 2 proxies are active but the renderings are different